# selenium webdriver - not getting All src image by xpath for amazon.co.uk

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

i am trying to fetch all the links for images present for the product -- https://www.amazon.co.uk/Autoglym-AG-035001-Interior-Shampoo/dp/B00114WOBC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1553519250&sr=8-1&keywords=715933155337

But in return i am getting just the one url link of the image.

not even i am getting 6 webelements when i tried to find the length of the list (product_image_url2)

```
          product_image_url2 = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-image- 

               container"]/ul/li/span/span/div/img')

            product_image_url2_count = len(product_image_url2)

             print product_image_url2_count

              image_url2 = []
                for curr_product_image_url2 in product_image_url2:
    image_url2.append(curr_product_image_url2.get_attribute("src"))
                product_dict['image url2']=image_url2
```

Comment: Can you show full code? I want to debug it.

Comment: Surely your code doesn't look anything like what you've posted or THAT'S the reason it likely doesn't work... please fix indents because indents matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct xpath to get the img element for the left hand side.

```
//li[@class='a-spacing-small item imageThumbnail a-declarative']//img
```

Below the code and output:

```
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='a-spacing-small item imageThumbnail a-declarative']//img")))
product_image_url2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='a-spacing-small item imageThumbnail a-declarative']//img")

product_image_url2_count = len(product_image_url2)

print(product_image_url2_count)

image_url2 = []
for curr_product_image_url2 in product_image_url2:
    print(curr_product_image_url2.get_attribute("src"))
    image_url2.append(curr_product_image_url2.get_attribute("src"))
```

**Output:**
    6
    [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31JLKXyjA5L.*SS40*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31JLKXyjA5L._SS40_.jpg)
    [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZZMf1JVfL.*SS40*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZZMf1JVfL._SS40_.jpg)
    [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416%2BBQU%2BtuL.*SS40*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416%2BBQU%2BtuL._SS40_.jpg)
    [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41CdeeG0HGL.*SS40*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41CdeeG0HGL._SS40_.jpg)
    [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41bZb0qgNPL.*SS40*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41bZb0qgNPL._SS40_.jpg)
    [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/219h80ACoQL.*SS40*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/219h80ACoQL._SS40_.jpg)

Comment: thanks:) it's working , just have 1 problem as change of  xpath for id  is less ascompared to xpath of class...can you help me with the xpath of id?

Comment: Also , can you help me with the xpath for product rating,below is the code for it :    
                                                              if self.hasXpath('//*[@id="reviewsMedley"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span/a/span/text()'):
                            product_rating = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reviewsMedley"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span/a/span/text()')
                            product_rating = product_rating.text.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()
                    product_dict['Rating']=product_rating.text

Comment: `li` does not have the class, but you can use this xpath based on id (not sure the numeric in id is static or changes) in the application `//span[@id='a-autoid-7']//img`.

Comment: Here is the xpath for the rating `// div[ @ id = 'reviewsMedley'] // span[ @ data - hook = 'rating-out-of-text']`.

Answer (score 1):

A css alternative to match those

```
#altImages img:not([alt])
```

The `#` is an id selector. The `img` is a type selector (for the tag). The `space` between the two is a `descendant combinator` meaning the `img` is a child of an element with id `altImages`. The `:not([alt])` specifies that the child `img` does not have an `alt` attribute. The `[]` is an attribute selector and `:not` is a CSS `pseudo-class`. Read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Autoglym-AG-035001-Interior-Shampoo/dp/B00114WOBC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1553519250&sr=8-1&keywords=715933155337'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
srcs = [item.get_attribute("src") for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#altImages img:not([alt])")))]
print(srcs)
```

Comment: i dont have any idea about CSS but thanks for the help:)

Comment: welcome. Did you try running the code?

Comment: I've added some notes in case you decide to learn more. With browser automation css selectors are generally faster than xpath so worth researching.

Comment: you are most welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is wrong. Try following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk/Autoglym-AG-035001-Interior-Shampoo/dp/B00114WOBC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1553519250&sr=8-1&keywords=715933155337')

product_image_url2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@id="a-autoid-8-announce"]/img')

product_image_url2_count = len(product_image_url2)

print (product_image_url2_count)

image_url2 = []
for curr_product_image_url2 in product_image_url2:
    image_url2.append(curr_product_image_url2.get_attribute("src"))

print(image_url2)
```

If you want store in dictionary try below code.

```
product_dict={}
for i in range(len(image_url2)):
    product_dict[i]=image_url2[i]

print(product_dict)
```

Output :

```
6
['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31JLKXyjA5L._SS40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZZMf1JVfL._SS40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416%2BBQU%2BtuL._SS40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41CdeeG0HGL._SS40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41bZb0qgNPL._SS40_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/219h80ACoQL._SS40_.jpg']


{0: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31JLKXyjA5L._SS40_.jpg', 1: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZZMf1JVfL._SS40_.jpg', 2: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416%2BBQU%2BtuL._SS40_.jpg', 3: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41CdeeG0HGL._SS40_.jpg', 4: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41bZb0qgNPL._SS40_.jpg', 5: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/219h80ACoQL._SS40_.jpg'}
```

Comment: it's not working for me and the xpath is not for images.